# Dynamically change form fields in Filament Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

Is it possible to generate new fields in a form based on a checkBoxList in filament dynamically,
Lets say I have a product and I checked the color option on it then an input field appear to add the value to that color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A little late on this, but I did it making the hidden property change dynamically.

```
Toggle::make('column')->hidden(function (callable $get) {
    if ($get('other_column') == 'x') {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
})
```

The 'other_column' must have the reactive() method.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use [Dependent fields](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/forms/advanced#dependant-fields--components)

Comment: Dependent fields work when the form is already generated (components have been created in the form array). I wanted to create new inputs dynamically.

Comment: Anw I solved it by using a wizard and a repeater. I enter the options then in the next step the user chooses the values then in the next step the user chooses SKU's and qty for different values combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want hidden from a user that is not admin (is_admin column is 0):

```
Toggle::make('column')->hidden(fn(callable $get) => Auth::user()->is_admin == 0);
```

Of course that you have create column name is_admin(tinyint or boolean) to do this